# Can the word "coexist" be used for more than two things/people/subjects/... etc?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

Can the word "coexist" be used for more than two things/people/subjects/... etc?

For example:

> The three communities complement each other and it will be marvelous to coexist side by side.

Comment: To me, the "side by side" seems more jarring than the "coexist". Many things can coexist, but I feel only two things can be side by side. That may just be me, though.

Comment: @oerkelens *The group of one hundred people linked arms and stood side by side in a line that stretched down the block.*

Comment: The prefix *co* means : "Together; joint; jointly; mutually: *coeducation*." ... "with or together, as in *co-exist*." – [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/co-) - I think the historical use of words like *coeducation* are tripping you up; there's more than two genders but the word still applies.

Comment: @JasonBassford I wouldn't say your example is an example of how "side by side" can be used for multiple things. What oerkelens was talking about was if the was a big bunch of something, described as being "side by side". Whilst your example is a line of a hundred people, respectively standing side by side.

Comment: > *di* 1 a prefix occurring in loanwords from Greek, where it meant “two,” “twice,” “double” (*diphthong*); on this model, freely used in the formation of compound words (*dicotyledon*; *dipolar*) and in chemical terms (*diatomic*; *disulfide*). – [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/di-)

Comment: @A.Kvåle What else can *side by side* possibly mean except for *in a row*? And how can that not apply to groups of people? At a track meet, multiple runners will run *side by side*. I see nothing about the expression that limits it to only two people.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the definition does not impose any limits on this:

> Exist at the same time or in the same place.

(source: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/coexist))

and there are some example sentences there as well which imply more than two subjects:

> - Modern Western medical practices coexist with traditional healing methods and the use of medicinal plants.
> - Nobody has convincingly explained how the birds, bees, flowers and hares of the uplands can coexist with a new influx of humans.
> - Amazon plants, evergreen pines, basil and other strange flora coexisted in perfect harmony.

Comment: In your first two examples, I interpret it as two things coexisting, but one of them is a collective. But the third example supports your thesis.

Answer (score 5):

From [wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coexistence):

> coexistence (countable and uncountable, plural coexistences):
>   The state of two or more things existing together, usually in a
>   temporal or spatial sense, with or without mutual interaction.

So yes, more than 2 subjects can coexist together.